# Flutter web resizing triggering bloc event?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, bloc

Whenever i resize my chrome browser it emits an event to add a new "variant" to my column, i have no idea what it could be triggering it. I know its triggering the on add variant event but i have no clue why its triggering when resizing, or zooming in or out.

Builder

```
                        BlocBuilder<VariantBloc, VariantState>(
                          builder: (context, state) {

                            if(state is AddedVariantState){
                              variants++;
                            }else if (state is DeletedVariantState){
                              variants--;
                              usecase.multipleUsecase.removeAt(state.index);
                            }

                            return Align( 
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: ListView.builder(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              itemCount: variants,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                usecase.multipleUsecase.add(MultipleAddServiceUsecase(index: index));
                                return VariantTextfield(
                                  usecase: usecase.multipleUsecase[index],
                                  index: index,
                                );
                              },
                              ),
                            );
                               
                          },
                        ),
```

Button that triggers event

```
class MarketplaceAddProductVariantButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const MarketplaceAddProductVariantButton({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: NeumorphicButton(
        onPressed: () {
          context
                .read<VariantBloc>()
                .add(OnAddVariantEvent());
        },
        margin:
            EdgeInsets.only(left: ScreenUtils.percentWidth(context, .5)),
        style: marketplaceButtonsNeuStyle.copyWith(
            boxShape:
                NeumorphicBoxShape.roundRect(BorderRadius.circular(17))),
        child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            height: ScreenUtils.percentHeight(context, 4.5),
            width: ScreenUtils.percentWidth(context, 12),
            child: AutoSizeText(
              'Agregar otro',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: _textStyle(),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Bloc that just emits event.

```
VariantBloc() : super(VariantInitial()) {
    on<OnAddVariantEvent>((event, emit) {
      emit(AddedVariantState(());
    });
```

Before resizing.
[image]

After.
[image]

Comment: you should not update `variants` in your `BlocBuilder` - any data should come directly from the bloc in your "state" class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it's **not** triggering a new event.
When you resize the window the `build` function will be called and so the `BlocBuilder` will be rebuilt, and if the **last** emitted state is `AddedVariantState` then this condition `if(state is AddedVariantState)` will be *true* and the `variants` variable will increase. The **opposite** behavior will happen if the last emitted state was `DeletedVariantState`.
That's why you should put the `variants` variable in the `VariantState` class.